# covert sql query output to json in python

Tags: python, json, pandasql

I want the output of the query to be consumed by charts js. 
They require json/array format for values and labels. 
I am new to python and pandas. 
My code -

```
import pandasql as pdsql

str="""select DISTINCT File_type,count(File_type) as files from final_df where Search_String='amy'  group by File_type """

result=pdsql.sqldf(str,locals())
```

result to be converted into json format.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. very easy and simple my bad.
data_values=results["xxxfieldxxx"].tolist()
data_labels=results["xxxfieldxxx"].tolist()